# Convergence in supremum norm of the convolution of two Fourier transforms implies pointwise convergence of each transform?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, statistics, fourier-analysis

I have a sequence of densities which have the form of mixtures:

$$ f_n (t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathbb{1}_{(t,\infty)}(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 - xt}}dP_n(x)$$

which are assumed to be well defined, i.e. the kernels are in $L^1(P_n)$ for every $n$. The $P_n$'s are probability measures. I know:

$$ \|f_n - f_0 \|_1 \rightarrow 0$$

where $f_0$ has also the mixture form, but mixes according to $P_0$. I would like to know if $P_n \rightsquigarrow P_0$ (weak convergence).

**Idea:**

My approach has been the following: I take the Fourier transform of each $f_n$ and $f_0$. Denote them respectively by $\hat{f_n}$ and $\hat{f_0}$. We know that:
$$ \| \hat{f_n} - \hat{f_0} \|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$$

Moreover we know, denoting the Fourier operator by $\mathcal{F}$ and by $\ast$ the convolution operation:

$$ \hat{f_n}(u) = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \ast \mathcal{F}(P_n)(u) \right) $$

From the above convergence in $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ I also know the following pointwise convergence for fixed $u$:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \ast \mathcal{F}(P_n)(u) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \ast \mathcal{F}(P_0)(u)$$

But how to prove that this implies pointwise convergence for fixed $u$:
$$\mathcal{F}(P_n)(u) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(P_0)(u)$$

**Q: Do you have any recommendation on how to tackle this problem or do you know any reference that could help?**